# How to align horizontal menu links in large resolution screen?

Tags: html, css

I have the horizontal menu. I have two problem with this menu are:

1. when I resize the browser, it will change to responsive menu.
2. when I open the page in big resolution  screen, menu not came in full screen.

I don't need responsive menu.

How to rectify following things:

1. Each link should equal width
2. space between the link name and left/right border should equal.
3. menu should be 100% width.

My code is here:

```
<div class="menudiv">
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/img1.png" alt="">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/img1.png" alt="">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/img1.png" alt="">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/img1.png" alt="">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/img1.png" alt="">Link1</a></li>       
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/img1.png" alt="">Link1</a></li>                  
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<style>
.menudiv {
    width: 94%;
    margin:0 3%;

}
.menu {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.menu ul ul {
    display: none;
    margin:4px 0 0 0;
}
.menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
.menu ul {
    background: #646464;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;

    -moz-border-radius: 13px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 13px;

}
.menu ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.menu ul li {
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.menu ul li:last-child{
    border:none;
}
}
.menu ul li:hover {
    background: #111312;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}
.menu ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
.menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 11px 42px;

    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul ul {
    background: #111312;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
.menu ul ul li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    border-right:none;
}
.menu ul ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
}
.menu ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #111312;
    color: #fff;
}
.menu ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu ul ul ul li {
    float: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid pink;
    position: relative;
}
.menu ul ul ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #95CEF1;
    color: #000;
}
.menu ul ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.head {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #789;
}
.foot {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #123;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` css properties to get what you wanted to achieve.

CSS:

```
.menu {
  display: table;
  width:100%;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style:none; margin:0 padding:0;
  display:table-row
}
.menu ul li{
  display:table-cell;
}
.menu ul li > a {
  display:block;
  padding:2px 4px;
    background:#333;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

More customization can be done for this type of css structure also. Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/ZnRcY/

Comment: This is definitely a cleaner solution than the way it is being implemented by the user.

Comment: yes @MathewMacLean, also, he would need to use media queries as well to get the `li`s floated next line (if he wanted), with overridden css.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

**[Working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cmkn6/8/)**

```
.menudiv {
   width: 94%;
   margin:0 3%;
   -moz-border-radius: 13px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 13px; background: #646464;

}
.menu {
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
   text-align:center;display:table;
   width:100%;
 }
.menu ul {

   margin: 0;
   list-style: none;
   position: relative;
   padding: 0;
   display:table-row;
}
.menu ul li {
   display:table-cell;
   border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
   border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Good Luck...

Comment: This is an answer, however, the poster wants the links spaced evenly across the menu, not just centered.

Comment: You can add `width:16%;` to your answer and it will be correct. I got 16% by taking 100% and dividing it by the number of menu items. **Updated fiddle here**: http://jsfiddle.net/cmkn6/6/

Comment: I also posted my comment before he updated the question. It was somewhat implied in the question. Regardless, you can update your answer. :)

Comment: Updated my above fiddle link....(http://jsfiddle.net/cmkn6/7/) please you can check now..

Comment: You can edit your existing answer with the correct CSS and correct fiddle instead of posting as a comment.

Comment: Updated...Check now...:)